# OpenSource Java lemmatizer

Tags: java, lemmatization

I would like to ask if you know any opensource java implemented lemmatizer.
Or if not opensource, at least any java implemented lemmatizer that can be used without having to pay for the licence.

Comment: Lemmatizers are language-specific. Specify your language of interest.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried GATE? Its written in Java. Much of it is pure Java, and some parts are just Java wrappers around other stuff. It probably has a plugin for the language or text-type your want to lemmatize.

http://gate.ac.uk/gate/doc/plugins.html

Its should be considered research quality, but its highly featured. I used it on my NLP course a few years ago for a question answering system.

(Also made by my alma mater, the University of Sheffield! :D)

Comment: Or more specifically http://gate.ac.uk/userguide/sec:parsers:stemmer, a wrapper for the [Snowball](http://snowball.tartarus.org) stemmers for a dozen or so different languages.

Answer (score 1):

The Stanford NLP package performs lemmatization. 
It is licensed under the GNU General Public License.

See the [Stanford NLP site](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/corenlp.shtml) for more specific information.

Comment: Stanford NLP license terms are very stringent. Though GPL - ther are few additional clause mentioned like it can only be used for non-profit projects